kernel dowgrade from 6.8.0-40 to 6.5.0-45
Hi I want to downgrade my kernel from 6.8.0-40 to 6.5.0-45 to solve the issue of freezes with my dell laptop with ryzen chipset :
I have downloaded the image for kernel 6.5.0-45, but when I boot using this kernel , no driver are loaded. My mouse , audio and network stop working as far I could diagnose and identify there might be alot more that havent loaded aswell ;
Can someone guide me how I can downgrade my kernel successfully without getting these errors :
I am new to Linux  , Thanks
update: dont download kernel 6.5.0-45 because it has several other bugs, resort to any other stable version

You are aware that the 6.5 kernel was from Ubuntu 23.10, has not received any security fixes since Ubuntu 23.10 reached EOL so I assume you're wanting this for a box you use offline?  You don't provide Ubuntu product/release details; so a supported kernel may be a safer option if you use a machine that is on a network or goes online.

I didnt know thatt. Yes I use it for local use , what kernel should I opt for ? Considering i have ubuntu 22.04 and amd ryzen , that has alot pf potential compatibility issues!!!

Ubuntu LTS offers you kernel stack choice; Server & flavor media installs and uses the GA kernel stack as it's seen as the most stable; which is 5.15 for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Ubuntu Desktop & later (.2 & higher) flavor media installs with the HWE which uses kernels from later releases before finally settling on the GA kernel stack from 24.04 (ie. 6.8), other options are OEM kernels.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  will cover GA/HWE & OEM kernel stack options (flavor media is same as 18.04 Desktop for all releases in that doc)

Other choices mean you take on security yourself; as you won't be using the Ubuntu patches for security; if you have the skillset & time required to backport patches yourself, you can use whatever kernel you like.. though if your machine is not used on a network, and doesn't share files/media with other systems, you can ignore security matters anyway

I am surprised to this it seems to be a common problem and fix. Has anyone attempted to find out what the cause is? https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/inspiron/resolving-freezing-and-internal-problems-of-ubuntu-2204-on-dell-g15-5530-2024/66d466aedfc136313f1cfd99 Has anyone tried it with 24.04 (with similar kernel)? https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/linux-general/dell-g15-5530-ubuntu-2204-lts-random-crash/66c5bd7796bc9473fe644b66?commentId=671b21d95c59063c7fa81506

I downgraded to kernel 6.5.0-060500-generic, but to my surprise the freezes have stopped but my fan control and sensors detect fail to work , can some one please tell me the most stable kernel for my machine : Ryzen 4500 U within dell 7402 2n1 laptop;
I will appreciate all yours help
